# Running React inside a WebView inside React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to run React inside **webView** inside React Native in a way that the React (non native one) code could still communicate with the native app?

The reason for this is that while some aspects of my app need the performance etc benefits of React Native, most of it can be run inside a **WebView** just fine, and I'd really want to avoid rewriting things that render to DOM.

I would also expose a bridge object to the JS inside the **WebView** somehow, i.e.:

```
 nativeBridge.doSomethingThatBrowserCant();
```

Comment: You could *try* to run React inside Cordova (previously called PhoneGap).

Comment: Yeah, but then I couldn't run react native?

Comment: We are doing the very thing you want in our company, it is possible. We have a different code base for what's in the webview and in RN. React Native is doing all navigation between the webviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [this package](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) does exactly what you need.

Essentially you are sending messages from a `WebView` to React Native and then you can do what you want with them. These messages are simple strings, but you can send more complex data with `JSON.stringify`.

```
const injectScript = `
    (function () {
        if (WebViewBridge) {
            WebViewBridge.onMessage = function (message) {
                if (message === 'native.didSomething') {
                    // Domething was done inside of React Native.
                    console.log('native.didSomething');
                }
            };

            WebViewBridge.send('native.doSomething');
        }
    }());
`;

class Example extends Component {
    doSomething() {
        // Do something inside of React Native.
        this.refs.webviewbridge.sendToBridge('native.didSomething');
    }

    onBridgeMessage(message) {
        const {webviewbridge} = this.refs;

        if (message === 'native.doSomething') {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <WebViewBridge
                ref="webviewbridge"
                onBridgeMessage={this.onBridgeMessage.bind(this)}
                injectedJavaScript={injectScript}
                source={{uri: "http://google.com"}}
            />
        );
    }
}
```